# Conversion string to URL failed

Tags: java, android, url

my problem is simple : when I try to convert string to URL:

```
urlTexte = new URL("http://www.prisonbreizh.com/VideoUpload/uploads/");
urlTexte = new URL(urlTexte, message[0]+".txt");
System.out.println("urlTexte="+ urlTexte);
```

`message[0]` is a string value (here "25").

I've got the answer : 
System.out: urlTexte=http://www.prisonbreizh.com/VideoUpload/uploads/25.txt

I would prefer : urlTexte=http://www.prisonbreizh.com/VideoUpload/uploads/25.txt

Thank you for your help, 
Gautier

Comment: I cannot see the difference between current result and desired result!

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were refering to the link highlighting not including `25.txt`, it should work as expected. Make sure you're using `URL` from `java.net.URL`.

[image]

**Note** that `toString` is not required when you are adding it to another string. I like to include it in my code to signal the fact that the object is not of type `String` and it is being converted. Beaware that this could cause `NullPointerException`. However if the object you're calling the `toString` method from should never be null, it is good to crash the program so you can investigate the real problem. If it can be null, use `String.valueOf()` instead.

Also @David Corral, you may not want to concat strings to generate URL's if they are variables (not the case here I'm just adding it as a note) as you might not know whether the last string contained trailing slash or not. In this case you know.